# Reverse marshalling in JSON

Tags: grails, groovy

In Grails, I am using

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller
```

to configure how objects are being converted to JSON.  However, when JSON comes back up from the UI, I would like to use the same mapping rules to create the Groovy object.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such purpose it is necessary to import the next package:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
```

Now you should be able to convert from Json to your groovy object by using the JSON class in the next way:

```
def groups = JSON.parse(params.groups);
```